# Firebase Dynamic Links open angular ionic app and receive url, but can't handle url and navigate from Appdelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links

The app is in ionic, angular and capacitor.
It works perfectly fine in Android, where i recieve the dynamic links in my app.component.ts function directly , but in ios the url are only in the AppDelegate.swift file
It is correctly being open by a dynamic link, but once in the functions in appdelegate

**Appdelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // Called when the app was launched with an activity, including Universal Links.
    // Feel free to add additional processing here, but if you want the App API to support
    // tracking app url opens, make sure to keep this call
      if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
          print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
          let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL)
          { (dynamicLink, error) in
              guard error == nil else{
                  print("Found an error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                  return
              }
              if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                   self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
              }
          }
          if linkHandled {
              return true
          }else {
              return false
          }
      }
```

i can't handle to send the user to a view like in approuting.ts or to send the url to my app.component.ts where i can handle it correctly. Do you know how can i do it?

**Appdelegate.swift**

```
 func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
        guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
            print("That's weird, my dynamic object has no URL")
            return
        }
        print("Your incoming link parameter is \(url.absoluteString)")

        // Handle the dynamic link URL here
        // You can extract parameters and navigate to specific screens based on the URL structure
        // For example, you can use URL components to extract path components or query parameters

        // Example:
        let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
        print("Your  parameter is \(url.pathComponents)")
        print("Your  parameter isss \(urlComponents?.path)")

        
        let notificationName = Notification.Name("MyAppDeepLinkNotification")
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: url)
        
        
        if let path = urlComponents?.path {
            if path.hasPrefix("/category/") {
                let venueID = path.replacingOccurrences(of: "/category/", with: "")
                print("The url is for category \(id)")
```

**app.component.ts**

An example of how it works correctly in Android, but in ios i never receive the url

```
this.deeplinks.route({
]        '/category/:id': CategoryPage,
```

Im trying to receive the dynamic link in my app.component.ts.
The iOS configuration should be fine because my app is being opened and I receive them in AppDelegate.swift